# Looking for a Python way to query ETH chain LAST prices

Tags: web3.py, 0x

I have no need for a smart contract or dApp. Using a local Python script, I just want to query different asset prices on ETH/EVM chains. No trading.

Querying the ETH chain seems very complicated, either querying a node directly, or via "provider account".

Looks like the 0x infrastructure/lib is aimed at providing liquidity/markets for ETH chains. Market makers are a possible way to get a "ball-park" price.

Is there an easy way to query LAST prices, or are DEX apis for market maker prices the easiest??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Trading Strategy real-time API](https://tradingstrategy.ai/api/explorer/) to get the latest OHLCV price candle of a certain DEX trading pair. This is not hard real-time, but good enough for ballpark use.

See `/candles` API endpoint. Then just pick the last candle as the base for the price.

No API key is needed. You can even use it with `curl` and `bash`.

[Here is a related Python script](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/trading-strategy/blob/master/scripts/download-jsonl-candles-raw-api.py) (not exactly what you are asking but close enough.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the API. The API is still in beta.

Comment: Thats gonna be a very useful API.

Are you planning on including the upcoming Pulsechain?... There is already a testnet to play with.

Comment: We prioritise the chains that reach out to us and help with development.

Comment: which chain(s) are next for inclusion?